# Mysql query to count occurrences of names, where they may have trailing characters?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a database that has a large number of rows with people's names in them.  However, the names may include trailing numbers.

For example, it could look like this:

```
Bob
Mike
Betsy
Bob 2/2
Kevin
Mike 2/3
Mike 3/3
```

I'd like to run a query so I can count the number of names, but I'm not sure how to do this so that "Mike X/Y" is included in the count for "Mike".

e.g. my counts would be:

```
Bob = 2
Mike = 3
Betsy = 1
Kevin = 1
```

Is this possible with mysql?

Comment: you seem to have some serious problems with your data. Why don't you fix that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit clunky but you could try testing for existence of a number by using a regular  expression then substringing to get everything before the first number

```
select newname, count(*)
from
(
select name,
            case when name REGEXP '[0-9]' = 1 then
            case 
                when locate('0',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('0',name) -2)
                when locate('1',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('1',name) -2)
                when locate('2',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('2',name) -2)
                when locate('3',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('3',name) -2)
                when locate('4',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('4',name) -2)
                when locate('5',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('5',name) -2)
                when locate('6',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('6',name) -2)
                when locate('7',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('7',name) -2)
                when locate('8',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('8',name) -2)
                when locate('9',name) > 0 then substring(name,1,locate('9',name) -2)
            end 
            else name
            end as newname
from t
) s 
group by newname
;
```